# Computing sine and cosine

Tags: java, runtime-error, nan

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class SinCos{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the angle for cosine: ");
        double anglecos=kb.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of expansions required:");
        int n=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the angle for sine:");
        double anglesin=kb.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of expansions required:");
        int n2=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Cosine: "+workCos(anglecos,n));
        System.out.println("Sine: " +workSin(anglesin,n2));

    }

    public static double workCos(double angle, int num){
        double ans=0;
        int times;
        for(int k=0;k<=num;k++){
            times=(2*k);

            ans=(ans + ((Math.pow(-1,k)*Math.pow(angle,times))/(fact(times))));

        }
        return ans;
    }

    public static double workSin(double angle, int num){
        double ans=(angle*Math.PI)/180;
        int times;
        for(int k=0;k<=num;k++){
            times=(2*k)+1;

            ans=(ans + ((Math.pow(-1,k)*Math.pow(angle,times))/(fact(times))));
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public static int fact(int num){

        if(num==0||num==1){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return num* fact(num-1);
        } 

    }
}
```

In this code above I'm trying to compute sine and cosine. However I'm
not getting correct results. It seems perfectly logical. To do this, I'm
using Taylor's series. can you tell me what's the problem with my
code?

Comment: And the input parameter values are?

Comment: "im not getting correct results" is highly unspecific. Try to debug the code please.

Comment: input is the angle and the number of times thee series is expanded

Comment: for example cos(90) doesnt give me answer 0 it gives -7.0985

Comment: and if n is larger than 15 i get answer NaN

Comment: "for example cos(90) doesnt give me answer 0 it gives -7.0985". You need to use radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly `13!` and above will overflow the `int` type in Java.

So any value of `num` above 12 in `fact(int num)` will give unexpected results.

One remedy is to use a `long` which gets you up to `19!`, by which time the series ought to have converged adequately. Using a `double` will yield more terms, with any loss of precision being well within the accuracy of your series approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula is a bit off. [Take a look here.](http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf)

Try sin like this:

```
public static double workSin(double angle, int num){
    double ans = 0;
    for(int n = 1; n <= num; n++) {
        ans += Math.pow(-1, n - 1) * Math.pow(angle, 2*n - 1) / fact(2*n - 1);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

and cos like this:

```
public static double workCos(double angle, int num) {
    double ans = 1;
    for(int n = 1; n < num; n++) {
        ans += Math.pow(-1, n) * Math.pow(angle, 2*n) / fact(2*n);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
    return ans;
}
```